# How can I set title depending upon the URL?

Tags: twig, symfony4

I am using Symfony as backend which is connected by encore to render the html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Homepage</title>

        {% block stylesheets %}
            {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="app">

    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
        {% block javascripts %}
            {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to change the title and meta based on the URL ? If path is `^/` set title & meta and when path is `^/profile` set different title & meta.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Why not set the title in your controller and put a variable in the Twig template?

Comment: @NicoHaase I mean in the `{ path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }` not the route

Comment: What does that mean? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Doesn't matter right? Every route get translated to a controller which then renders a view. You should perfectly be able to assign the title and meta tags in the controller before sending a response